# ClearCase Checkin Message

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

In ClearCase GUI, when I tried to check-in, an empty comment field will be shown, which I can fill in check-in messages.

Is it possible to set template for this message?

For example, when the team need to checkin, below message will be shown, and each team member can just fill in the commit message.

Reviewer:
Test suggestion:

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native template mechanism that I know of.

You can try and see if the [ClearCase environment variables](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/env_ccase.htm) could help, like setting in a pre-op checkin trigger a:

```
CLEARCASE_CMNT_PN
```

> The path name of the file in which cleartool and multitool cache the most recent user-supplied comment. Defining or removing this EV enables or disables comment caching.

(and make sure that file contains a message template)

That [thread from 2005](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013715725) though mentions:

> The `CLEARCASE_*` environment variables are effectively read only (changes to them have no effect.)
>   Some potential options are:
>
> - A) reject comments that do not meet your template and make the user fix them and redo the checkin/out
> - B) put a wrapper around checkout/in operations to meet your template needs
> - C) use '`ct chevent`' to change the comment during a postop trigger
> - D) use attributes, hlinks, or labels to store the information instead of using the comment field. (You can apply the attributes, hlinks, or labels during the preop)
>
> I'm thinking that `C` or `D` might be your better choices.

Comment: I just want template to show up in the GUI when checking in, I tried the CLEARCASE_CMNT_PN solution, the template defined in the file won't show up in the GUI.
Anyway, thanks